# AVS & CCV validation using authorize.net AIM & CIM methods

Tags: authorize.net

I want to validate street address, zip code & CCV of customer during transaction processing using AIM & CIM methids of authorize.net. So for AVS , I have enabled AVS filter and mark allow for transaction when street address & zip code is matched only other wise transaction is declined & for CCV validation , I enabled card code verification filter.

Please confirm that , Is this sufficient configuration required for AVS & CCV validation while processing transaction using authorize.net AIM & CIM methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your fraud configuration is sufficient to protect you from attackers who have compromised an account from using an existing billing profile to made an unauthorized purchase.

This is the same type of verification Amazon performs for one click purchases.